# Register types by base type and resolve at runtime with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I've got the following setup:

```
public interface IServiceBase {}

public interface IService1: IServiceBase {}
public interface IService2: IServiceBase {}
// ... Snip lots of lines
public interface IService999: IServiceBase {}

public interface IConnection { T GetService<T>() where T: IServiceBase; }
```

`IConnection` is registered with Autofac. Calling `GetService()` on it will dynamically implement the given interface and return an instance.

Now I'd like to make some kind of generic registration for all `IServiceBase`-derived types. I don't want to register every `IServiceX` manually, and I don't want to do assembly scanning (though I guess it's an option).

In not-really-legal-code, this is what I want:

```
ContainerBuilder.Register<IServiceBase>(x=> x.Resolve<IConnection>().GetService);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed `IRegistrationSource` feature of Autofac.